# Конструкция "из-за того что" - нужна ли запятая перед что?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы

Из-за того что он уснул в снегу, холод сильно повредил его внутренние органы. Нужна ли запятая перед "что"?

Answer (score 1):

Запятая нужна.

Придаточные предложения, присоединяемые союзом 'из-за того, что', выделяются запятыми. При этом первая запятая обычно ставится не перед союзом, а между его частями (перед словом 'что').

Последний пример по ссылке такой же, как здесь:

http://old-punctum.ru/punctum.php?sid=821